# D associative arrays - pass by value or pass by reference?

Tags: pass-by-reference, d, associative-array, pass-by-value

Say I have an associative array of pointers to structs to strings, where the struct is called `Foo`; the type will be `Foo*[string]`. Suppose I also have a function with the following signature: `void bar (Foo*[string] baz)`. Will `baz` be passed to `bar` by value or by reference? I've not found any documentation about this, and I'm curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By reference - any modifications to an existing AA will be observed outside of the function.

However, there is a corner case for when the associative array is `null`. In that case, initializing the AA by adding the first element will not be observed outside of the function. If the AA to be modified might be `null`, you should pass it by-`ref`.

Answer (score 4):

It's like in Java. It's **pass-by-value**, but the value is a reference.
So you can't change the reference itself, but you can modify the AA it refers to.

Answer (score 3):

AAs in D are implemented as a struct https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/master/src/rt/aaA.d#L82-85, which is pass-by-value. But this struct contains pointer to other struct. And if this pointer to struct is not null, than all modification inside function will be visible in caller side.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in D will be passed by reference but goes in as a "fat pointer". You should watch out for this situation particularly.

In this case the call-site is not affected by re initializing the array ex.:
**arrX = [ new, values, here ];**

While this case does affect the call-site: **arrX[index] = newVal;**

If what you want is to disallow either case to occur, you can prefix them with the **in** or **const** modifiers.

Source: The D Programming Language - Andrei Alexandrescu - Addison Wesley.